# How to make N executions of the same program run at different cores at 100% in Linux/macOS?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, parallel-processing

## QUESTION

How can I run different instances of the same program in different cores at 100%?

## CONTEXT

I am running a C++11 code in an iMac Pro (2017) with OS High Sierra 10.13.6. The corresponding executable is called 'bayesian_estimation'.

When I run one instance of this program, one of the cores is doing that task at 100%, as you can see here:

[image]

If I run more instances, the CPU% of each of them goes down. But most of the cores remain idle! Why are not they being used? See, for example, what happens when 3 'bayesian_estimation' processes are running:

[image]

Or when I execute 7:

[image]

Ideally in the last picture, I would like to have 7 cores completely busy, each of them running one 'bayesian_estimation' process.

## EDIT 1

I proceed to give more information that might help to identify the problem. I compiled my code as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g bayesian_estimation.cpp -o bayesian_estimation -O2 -larmadillo
```

And *all* libraries and packages that I have used are the following:

```
#include <iostream>     // Standard input and output functions.
#include <iomanip>      // Manipulate stream input and output functions.
#include <armadillo>    // Load Armadillo library.
#include <sys/stat.h>   // To obtain information from files (e.g., S_ISDIR).
#include <dirent.h>     // Format of directory entries.
#include <vector>       // To deal with vectors.
```

Comment: I suspect an IO bottleneck with all the instances competing for HDD's attention. But it is impossible to say without more information.

Comment: @bolov , I have appended to the question all the relevant information I can think of, see the section 'Edit 1'. I would be glad to add anything else that might be of help. Do not hesitate to let me know about it.

Comment: IIRC, in Linux, you can use `numactl` program to set affinity of a process to 
a particular core. Don't know whether this program is available in OS X.

Comment: You can set different core affinity but you shouldn’t need to: the OS will already try to balance the tasks on different cores. And in fact this works very reliably. I therefore strongly suspect that bolov is right: your tasks are facing IO contention and need to wait for each other. If the tasks were CPU bound, they would use all available CPUs at close to maximum load. — Another thing, consider setting `-O3`. The difference is often slight but in some cases it can be drastic, and there’s no good reason against it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph , I have tried with `-O3` and the result is the same.

Comment: the libraries used are mostly irrelevant. What we would need to know is the algorithm and the implementation used. Unfortunately that would pretty much require to post the whole program which even if you were willing to do will make your question ill-received (code dumps without any analysis are ill-received here and on good reason). I am afraid you need to investigate the problem yourself. I have given you a possible culprit. You need to analyse and profile your program to identify the bottleneck yourself. There isn't a general magic solution that can fix your program.

Comment: Besides an IO bottleneck, you might also face a memory bottleneck. Minor variation, still: in either case the CPU is waiting on data.

Comment: @bolov Thank you, that was of great help. Now that I see that my question is misleading, should I delete it, answer it myself...?

Comment: First thing you want to do is enable `PROCESSOR` column in `htop`. The second thing find out what process/thread state `U` means on your platform - probably uninterruptible sleep waiting for I/O.

Comment: @Godoy You shouldn't edit your question to include the answer. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question and I think in this case this is what you should do. Also why `arma_rng::set_seed_random()` causes the bottleneck I think it's an interesting question. Ask a separate question for this, but please do provide the necessary information to be answerable. Ideally you should create a [MCVE] that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the origin of the bottleneck that @bolov mentions in the comments. It arises due to the use of `arma_rng::set_seed_random()` in the code to generate random numbers with the Armadillo library. If I remove that line of the code, the problem is gone.

A question going deeper into this issue and providing with a reproducible example is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209631/c11-parallelization-bottleneck-in-armadillos-set-seed-random).