# C++11 parallelization: bottleneck in Armadillo's set_seed_random()

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, parallel-processing, armadillo

In C++11, the use of `arma_rng::set_seed_random()` generates a bottleneck. I show a way to reproduce it.

Consider this simple code:

```
#include <armadillo>    // Load Armadillo library.
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
bool jj = true;
while ( jj == true ){
    arma_rng::set_seed_random();            // Set the seed to generate random numbers.
    double rnd_number = randu<double>();    // Generate a random number.
}

}
```

I compiled it with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g bayesian_estimation.cpp -o bayesian_estimation -O2 -larmadillo
```

When I run the executable in a terminal, I see that one of the cores is handling it with a CPU% close to 100%. If I run more instances of it, the CPU% of each corresponding process is reduced, but no new (and idle!) cores are used. I illustrate this kind of behavior in detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53205907/how-to-make-n-executions-of-the-same-program-run-at-different-cores-at-100-in-l).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that Armadillo takes the seed for `set_seed_random()` from the pool of true random numbers that is maintained by the OS (e.g. /dev/random on most *NIX OS). Since this needs a physical source of entropy (usually, the timing of keystrokes, network events, other interrupt sources is used), this pool is finite and can be exhausted faster than new random numbers can be generated.

And in your case, I would assume that one executable running at full speed is depleting the pool at roughly the same rate that new entropy is added. As soon as you add a second, third, ..., they stall while waiting for new random numbers to enter the pool.

Comment: It makes sense. Is there a simple way to know how big that pool is and how often it is filled?

Comment: I don't know an "official" way, but for a rough estimate, you could perhaps run ’dd if=/dev/random of=tmpfile’ for a minute and see how much data you get.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code for a pseudo random number generator and you'll find out that instantiating it and/or giving it a new seed can be a rather costly process. You should generally only instantiate/seed *one* for each thread and use it for the rest of the threads life.

```
#include <armadillo>    // Load Armadillo library.
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    bool jj = true;
    arma_rng::set_seed_random();            // Set the seed to generate random numbers.

    while ( jj == true ){
        double rnd_number = randu<double>();    // Generate a random number.
    }    
}
```

It looks like [arma_rng::set_seed_random()](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/9.200.x/include/armadillo_bits/arma_rng.hpp) uses a variety of fallbacks unless `ARMA_USE_CXX11` is defined. My guess is that it gets lucky when when trying `/dev/urandom`. Do `man urandom` for more info about that.